# How to force .NET 3.5 application run on .NET 4.5 runtime?

Tags: .net, .net-4.5

I'm trying to implement the solution described here: [Can I use a .NET 4 feature while targeting .NET 3.5 SP1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6119614/can-i-use-a-net-4-feature-while-targeting-net-3-5-sp1/6134742#6134742). It works fine when a .NET 3.5 application runs on .NET 4.0. However, on .NET 4.5 the app runs on .NET 3.5 environment. I have tried the following:

```
<supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5"/>
<supportedRuntime version="v4.0"/>
<supportedRuntime version="v2.0.50727"/>
```

with no success. `Environment.Version` still tells `2.0.50727.5456` while on .NET 4.0 everything is OK.

Is there a way to force .NET 3.5 app use .NET 4.5 if available?

Comment: is this local or on IIS if IIS you could try adding it to a 4.5 pool

Comment: What version of Visual Studio?

Comment: All: I'm developing a desktop app in VS2010 targeting .NET 3.5 and I want it be able on run on 3.5, 4.0 and 4.5. I want the app to be actually run on .NET version as higher as possible on the user's machine.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's my fault: app.config accidentally was not copied onto build directory. Everything works with:

```
<supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5"/>
<supportedRuntime version="v4.0"/>
<supportedRuntime version="v2.0.50727"/>
```

Comment: for me its not working.how u generate and name your config file.I am also trying same but no luck.help me