# Winform images (ResourceManager) not visible on Windows 10

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-10, resourcemanager

I have a Windows form application that works fine on Windows 7, but when opened in Windows 10, image files using **ResourceManager** don't show up. Application is using .Net 3.5 framework. Following is a bit of code:

```
static readonly System.Resources.ResourceManager rm = new System.Resources.ResourceManager("ImageResources", Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

rm.GetObject("ImageName");
```

Following is the error:

> Could not find any resources appropriate for the specified culture or
>   the neutral culture.  Make sure was correctly embedded or linked into
>   assembly at compile time, or that all the satellite assemblies
>   required are loadable and fully signed.
>   System.Resources.MissingManifestResourceException:

Is it due to some kind of incompatibility or Windows 10 is somehow restricting ResourceManager class to use all those images?

Comment: Are you sure that the images had been copy correctly?

Comment: Same setup is being installed on Windows 7, works fine. When installed on Windows 10, images don't show up.

Comment: Check what .NET framework is install on Windows 10.

Comment: Windows 10 comes pre loaded with .Net framework 4.

Comment: You're application is compiled with .NET framework 3.5. You should installed v3.5 to avoid forcing your application to run in v4.

Comment: I actually installed .net 3.5 framework first on Windows 10, as it was not allowing me to install the application with 3.5 framework.

Comment: Check you config file and make sure you're using 3.5.

Comment: I have nothing mentioned about targeted framework in config file.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3953063/how-to-force-an-application-to-use-net-3-5-or-above

Comment: Tried using it but no use.

Comment: @FaizanRabbani, can you provide *.config file content of your application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was eventually resolved by adding `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture` in `rm.GetObject` method parameter i.e.

```
rm.GetObject("ImageName", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to check value of **Environment.Version** (with some MessageBox for example) on the target machine.
If you get 4.0 then you need to change configuration file as was proposed by Dr. Stich.
If you don't have configuration file then create it like described there:
[How to: Add an Application Configuration File to a C# Project](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184658.aspx)

And change it content to something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
<startup>
  <supportedRuntime version="v2.0.50727" />
</startup>
</configuration>
```

Runtime version you can get on [supportedRuntime Element page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w4atty68.aspx)

Comment: Is it due to .net framework incompatibility? ResourceManager not able to load properly due to this?

Comment: I can not be sure on a 100%, but if you check Environment.Version on target machine and get v4.0 (if you add in your code messagebox that show value of Environment.Version) then you can be sure that it cause of .net framework version compatibility